# Count in SQL With Group

Tags: sql

Please help me, I want to ask how to count with group use SQL server syntax. The sample is like this:

```
Table : Leasing
Field : LeasingName
Data :  - PANIN
        - CLIPAN
        - MEGA
        etc

Table : Insurance    
Field : InsuranceName
Data  : - BUANA
        - MUGI
        - BESS
        etc      

Table Customer
NoCust      LeasingName        InsuranceName    --> Field Name
00001       PANIN   
00002       PANIN              BESS   
00003       MEGA               BUANA
00004       CLIPAN             MUGI
```

The result I want is:

I want to select and count by group leasingname and insurancename with all data table : insurance and leasing

so the result can be like this :

```
| PANIN  |  CLIPAN  | MEGA  |  --> All data from table Leasing 
  2         1         1

| BUANA  |  MUGI    | BESS  | --> All Data from table Insurance
  1         1         1
```

All the result count get from count in table customer
Please help me.

Comment: Do you need one table for the results or two?

Comment: result two tables. But dont display in one row. i want display in 2 rows. the first row is count data leasing and the second row is count data insurance

Answer (score 1):

```
Use PIVOT Table to get your result :

CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable (NoCust INT , LeasingName VARCHAR(100) ,     
InsuranceName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #CustomerTable (NoCust , LeasingName  , InsuranceName ) 
SELECT 00001,'PANIN','' UNION ALL
SELECT 00002,'PANIN','BESS' UNION ALL  
SELECT 00003,'MEGA','BUANA' UNION ALL
SELECT 00004,'CLIPAN','MUGI'


 SELECT CLIPAN , MEGA , PANIN
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT LeasingName , COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM #CustomerTable
    GROUP BY LeasingName
 ) A
 PIVOT 
 (
      MAX(Cnt) FOR LeasingName IN ([CLIPAN],[MEGA],[PANIN])
 )pvt


 SELECT [BESS],[BUANA],[MUGI]
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT InsuranceName , COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM #CustomerTable
    GROUP BY InsuranceName
 ) A
 PIVOT 
 (
     MAX(Cnt) FOR InsuranceName IN ([BESS],[BUANA],[MUGI])
 )pvt
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DSKDKW60189)

Comment: Mr.Mansoor, if the table insurance and leasing have more data how can we make like the syntax. Before sorry i'm not explain i still use sql server 2000 so can't use pivot.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    count( * ) RecordsPerGroup,
    COUNT( * ) OVER () AS TotalRecords
from temptable
group by column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4
```

Comment: you should add  a brief explanation of your answer

Comment: How can u use temptable. the master data have 2 tables. i want display all the data from table insurance and leasing and get the total from table customer